# datetime field won't update in MySQL Database

Tags: php, mysql, datetime

Hi I am having an issue with updating a users last login time in my database, if I set it to update a different column it works perfectly, but it just does not work when i try to update the specific column "lastlogin".

My code:

```
    @mysql_query("UPDATE my_users SET lastlogin=NOW() WHERE id=".$_SESSION["id"]);

My DB column:

column name: lastlogin

type: datetime

Null: No

Default: 0000-00-00 00:00:00
```

Anything wrong with the way the column is setup in the DB? Like I mentioned above if I was to tell it to put NOW() in another column it works fine.

Comment: I recommend you remove the `@` at sign before `mysql_query`. If there's an error, I think we'd want to know about it. Another recommendation: assign the dynamically generated SQL statement to a variable in a separate step, and then echo or vardump the variable for debuggin, before calling `mysql_query`, We could take that SQL statement to another client for testing. And what is the datatype of `id` column? Is the value of `$_SESSION["id"]` integer?  `mysql_` interface functions are deprecated, and removed PHP 7. Use PDO or mysqli and prepared statements with bind placeholders.

Comment: @spencer7593 thanks for the advice. I know the query is working because if I change  "lastlogin" to any other db field it will insert the data into the database. The problem is when trying to insert into the "lastlogin" column.

Comment: rule out some possibilities... there isn't a `BEFORE UPDATE` trigger defined on the table that's assigning a value to `lastlogin`, there's not an `AFTER UPDATE` that's throwing an error and rolling back the transaction. I suggest you try updating *two* columns, assign NOW() to both `logindate` and another table column. And see if the update of the other column is successful.

Comment: There are no excuses for using such a long since deprecated api, and no further energy should be expended on it.

Answer (score 1):

Solved. There was another similar statement further down which was over riding this one! How stupid of me but easy to miss!

Answer (score 0):

use [`mysql_error`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-error.php) to try and find what is wrong, then post that into here so we can help if you need it. (Would comment but to low rep)

Answer (score 0):

From my experience in the past, mysql_query() doesn't necessarily substitute variables before executing sql. Try writing in this format. Also use mysql_error to check if there are any issues with your code execution:

```
$sql = "UPDATE my_users SET lastlogin=NOW() WHERE id=".$_SESSION["id"]; 
mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
```

If there is no error, then there are few possibilities as to why the laslogin entry is not happening:

- $_SESSION["id"] does not hold any value and no value is being passed to mysql.
- There is no id matching with $_SESSION["id"].

To debug:

- Also try updating some other columns.
- You might also want to check if you are using correct extensions like PDO..

Also found that, earlier version of mysql doesn't support updating datetime column with now(). In that case try resetting column type to TIMESTAMP. Refer this for details: https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=27645

Comment: Hi, like I mentioned, the PHP code is working fine, I can tell it to write to a different column in the database without a problem.

Comment: Strange. Try resetting column type to TIMESTAMP. Referring this https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=27645